link local prisma database project into other projects
I have two services that is in need of my prisma project that has all the types and prisma client, now I need a way to install it into both projects.
My database project only has one file prisma.ts that exports the prisma client, I also need the types of my models as well.
my database project package.json
{
  "name": "pricing-oygula-database",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "prisma.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "amunim",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.21.1",
    "prisma": "^5.21.1",
    "tsc": "^2.0.4",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  }
}

I tried npm link and then cd into my next.js project to npm link <project name> but that does not work.
